# SPARQL INSERT not working with PUT method. why?

Tags: sparql, put, fedora-commons

I am trying to create a new object with PUT method and to add some of my own prefixes with SPARQL query. But, the object is being created without the added prefixes. It works with POST and PATCH though. Why and is there alternative way for SPARQL to use with PUT method and add using user-defined prefixes?

```
 PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
 PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
 PREFIX indexing: <http://fedora.info/definitions/v4/indexing#>

 DELETE { }
 INSERT {
   <> indexing:hasIndexingTransformation "default";
      rdf:type indexing:Indexable;
      dc:title "title3";
      dc:identifier "test:10";
 }
 WHERE { }
```

What I am saying was all the above values specified in the `insert` clause are not added at all.

EDIT1:

```
url = 'http://example.com/rest/object1'
payload = """
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX indexing: <http://fedora.info/definitions/v4/indexing#>
PREFIX custom: <http://customnamespaces/custom#/>
DELETE { }
INSERT {
<> indexing:hasIndexingTransformation "default"; 
rdf:type indexing:Indexable; 
dc:title "title1";
custom:objState "Active";
custom:ownerId "Owner1";
dc:identifier "object1";
}
WHERE { }
""" 
headers = {
    'content-type': "application/sparql-update",
    'cache-control': "no-cache"
    }
response = requests.request("PUT", url, data=payload, headers=headers, auth=('username','password'))
```

Comment: If there is no other way, then I need to do it in two steps: 1. Create object with PUT 2. update the object with PATCH

Comment: Can you be a little more explicit about how you are invoking `POST` and `PUT`?

Comment: Hi Scott, I have added it in the question.

Comment: What does the errant output look like?  Also have you tried replacing the qnames with their full URLs?

Comment: There is no error at all...a object is created using this method as usually, but it doesn't contain the attributes I have mentioned in the query. And what is qnames?

Comment: I said "errant data", not error.  A qname is a prefix plus a local name.  E.g. custom:objState is a qname for `<http://customnamespaces/custom#objState>`

Answer (score 0):

Prefixes are not triples and therefore cannot be added using a SPARQL query.  You can always specify prefixes in the SPARQL query and it will generate the correct URI for storage in your triple store.

Also note that your `custom` namespace is errantly defined by ending with both a hash and a slash.  It should be either `PREFIX custom: <http://customnamespaces/custom#>` or `PREFIX custom: <http://customnamespaces/custom/>`.

I.e. by your query indexing:hasIndexingTransformation will be stored in the triple store as `<http://fedora.info/definitions/v4/indexing#hasIndexingTransformation>`.

There is no reason to store the prefix in the triple store (actually, prefixes are an artifact of the text serialization, not the data itself), so you can subsequently query this data in one of two ways.

1) Using a prefix

```
PREFIX indexing: <http://fedora.info/definitions/v4/indexing#>
SELECT ?o {
   [] indexing:hasIndexingTransformation ?o .
}
```

2) Using the full URI:

```
SELECT ?o {
   [] <http://fedora.info/definitions/v4/indexing#hasIndexingTransformation> ?o .
}
```

Comment: Hi Scot, you have misunderstood my words. I haven't put them properly. Actually, what I was trying is to create a new object plus adding custom properties at the same time. It works with POST, but not with PUT.